# split directory paths and use with regex, bash

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

i am trying to upload some files to s3 and have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
s3upload() {
    echo $1
    for f in $(find $d \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f)
    do
        extension=$(file $f | cut -d ' ' -f2 | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
        mimetype=$(file --mime-type $f | cut -d ' ' -f2)
        echo $mimetype
        fullpath=$(readlink -f $f)
        #response=$(s3cmd put -v setacl --acl-public \
        #       --add-header="Expires: $(date -u +"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT" --date "+1 years")" \
        #       --add-header="Cache-Control: max-age=1296000, public" \
        #       --mime-type=$mimetype \
        #       $fullpath \
        #       s3://ccc-public/catalog/)
        #echo $response
    done
}
BASE='./nas/cdn/catalog'
echo $BASE
for d in $(find . -type d -regex '\{$BASE}/[^.]*')
do
    echo "Uploading $d"
    s3upload $d

done
```

the issue is that i can't pass the $BASE to the regex

basically i want to append the directory path after catalog/ to the s3 path s3://ccc-public/catalog/

```
./nas/cdn/catalog/swatches
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res/back
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res/front
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res/back
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res/front
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/thumbs
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length/high_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length/low_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/cropped
./nas/cdn/catalog/drawings
```

to s3://ccc-public/catalog/

any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The variables in 'single quotes' will be never evaluated. You need "double quotes" for `$BASE`.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words.

Moreover, instead of using `for` loops, you should use `while IFS= read -r` to treat files with special characters like spaces and other surprises.

---

Also, [find](/questions/tagged/find) can do the whole work alone :

```
BASE='./nas/cdn/catalog'

find . -type d -regex "${BASE}/[^.]*" -exec s3upload {} \;
```